# How far in topics does Spivak's Calculus cover?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, machine-learning, learning

For example, would it go all the way to Differential Equations? I want to get my money's worth. I want to learn up to Differential Equations for now, but I want a rigorous proof based style even though I'm just planning on using Differential Equations for applications. (Specifically Machine Learning on Climate Data).

Comment: Cannot you read its table of contents? You can read it [here](http://sciguide.wikidot.com/textbooks:spivak) for example.

Comment: I just did. I couldn’t find it earlier which is why I asked. It doesn’t cover diff eq from what I saw.

Comment: No, Spivak doesn't cover differential equations. But there is a book by Murray Spiegel called *Applied Differential Equations* which is actually a very nice introduction to them.